# Old monitor Flashing

Tags: laptop, display

I have this old monitor which was for my old computer. I abandoned it in a storage space for about 6 years because it was working for 2-3 seconds and then would turn off. If I turn it off and on again it would do the same thing (work for 2-3 seconds) and eventually I just forgot about it.

Some weeks ago I got it back from storage and plugged it to my laptop and it worked just fine for about 2 days. The next day the same problem was back. I scouted the internet for literally hours and hours to find a solution and all of the forums and guides said it's either broken and  I should just replace it or the backlight stopped working and so on.

I've tried everything possible and changed all possible settings, but nothing worked, until the day I decided to say goodbye to it. Surprisingly it works and it has worked for weeks but then the same problem was back. One day later the problem wasn't there anymore, weeks passed and this morning the same thing happened. I just made my laptop sleep and turn on again, a couple of restarts and one shut down and it's back working now (probably for the next 3-4 weeks) and I'm writing my problem literally through it.

Some technicians said it might be the VGA cable but I'm 100% sure that's not it.

What could it possibly be and how can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you so sure it's not the VGA cable?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy enough to substitute the cable and see if that is the issue.

More likely the backlight tube has failed and become intermittent. That is why it works sometimes and not others. Resting for a few years may have allowed it to work a bit longer before going out again.

It is worth repairing?  Probably not. You have to take the monitor apart, remove the tube (can be delicate) and find a replacement.

I suggest that a new monitor may be more economical in terms of both time and money.